# Python exec() in other context

Tags: python

I would like to `exec()` code in the context of another function. Just doing it naively like

```py
def f1():
    exec("b = 5")


def f2():
    f1()
    print(b)


f2()
```

won't work because `b` is not defined in `f2`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/s.py", line 10, in <module>
    f2()
  File "/tmp/s.py", line 7, in f2
    print(b)
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

I do not want to pass `"b = 5"` to `f2`.

Is it perhaps possible to pass the context of `f2` to exec? Any hints?

Comment: You've completely changed your code sample since I posted that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `exec` contexts through the two other parameters it supports:

```
exec(object[, globals[, locals]])
```

So to marshal the context from the previous function, include those as well. For example to marshal the local context only:

```
>>> def f1(code, ctx):
...   exec(code, {}, ctx)
>>> def f2():
...   a = 42
...   f1("print(a + 1)", locals())
>>> f2()
43
```

To work with the modified context in future calls, own the context you're sending in yourself:

```
>>> def f2():
...   ctx = {'a': 42}
...   f1("a += 1", ctx)
...   print(ctx)
...
>>> f2()
{'a': 43}
```

Comment: Thanks Mats. Thats already great for getting context into `exec`! How would you get something out of exec?

Comment: You own the context instead, i.e. you give a dict that you keep a reference to, and that dict will be modified as the context. I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
class Context:
    pass


def f1(code, c):
    exec(code)


def f2():
    c = Context()
    c.a = 42
    f1("print(c.a + 1)", c)


f2()
```

where you add the variable to a context class and pass that along.